# How can I access my website using my IP instead of localhost?

Tags: localhost, ip

I'm connected to the internet through wi-fi, and I want to access my website using my IP. This is the link when using localhost:

```
https://localhost:44324/
```

My IP is 192.168.1.112

However when I enter the link https://192.168.1.112:44324/ its says that it's not possible to access the website. Why is this happening?

Comment: P.S. are you trying to access your website from a device that is on your network but which is not the one running your website locally?

Comment: I'm trying to access it on the same computer, not from a different device

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities. In descending order of likeliness:

- Your web server is configured to listen on a set of network interfaces that doesn't include the one with the IP `192.168.1.112` (typically this is when it is configured to **only** listen on `localhost`).
- You are trying to access the IP address from a computer that isn't on the same local network.
- Your networking stack can't access its own IP address from itself (very unlikely, this problem more often occurs when trying to access the public facing IP address of an Internet router from within the LAN that router connects to the Internet).

This assumes that the problem it gives is that it can't connect to that IP address. It might also be offering up an HTTPS error message (e.g. because the security certificate doesn't say it is for `192.168.1.112`).

Comment: But how do i fix it?

Comment: @TeresaAlves — The obvious first step would be to look at your webserver's configuration to see what network interfaces it was listening on.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Is there any tutorial?